# Creating a PDF at Runtime and fill that with data and showing it in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a set of Text Fields which the user will fill and when he clicks on the save button ,we should create a PDF through code and fill it with the user filled data and show the PDF on iPhone Screen.

Answer (score 3):

The best starting point on how to generate PDFs in iOS is the [Apple's Drawing and Printing Guide for iOS - Generating PDF Content](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/GeneratingPDF/GeneratingPDF.html) that is including sample code how to generate a PDF page (or a document with several pages). Within each page you can use any Quartz function to draw content. If you give a bit more details what you are planning to draw it is easier to help you.